# Usage of const in C#

Tags: c#, oop, constants, readonly-attribute

I would like to make the cert variable below to be a const? When I do that, I get an error, "The expression being assigned to cert must be a constant". I have seen articles online asking to convert it to static readonly as opposed to const, and also saying that to be a const, the value should be known at compile time.

**I have two questions**

1. Is it not possible for cert to be a const variable, since I do not
   want it to be modified?
2. I tried making the cert variable a readonly, and that too gives me
   an error, "The modifier readonly is not valid for this item".

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IAMAGoodDeveloper
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            programStart();
        }

        private static void programStart()
        {
            var myFactory = new MyFactory();
            var secretsProvider = myFactory.GenerateKeyProvider();
            const int cert = secretsProvider.GetKey("arg");
        }
    }
}
```

MyFactory.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IAMAGoodDeveloper
{
    public class MyFactory
    {
        public KeyGen GenerateKeyProvider()
        {
            return new KeyGen();
        }
    }

    public class KeyGen
    {
        public int GetKey(string arg)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use const with instantiated objects. 
A good alternative would be a static readonly field at class-level though.

Comment: Like this you mean, public static class Program
    {
        static MyFactory myFactory = new MyFactory();
        static KeyGen secretsProvider = myFactory.GenerateKeyProvider();
        static readonly int cert = secretsProvider.GetKey("arg");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            programStart();
        }

        private static void programStart()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cert);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
That works.

Answer (score 3):

`const` is compile time keyword that will replace all references to you're const variable with a hard coded value in the compiled code

```
public class MyClass
{
    private const int MyNumber = 2;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyNumber);
    }
}
```

When this gets compiled the resulting code looks like this

```
public class MyClass
{


    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(2);
    }
}
```

It will have been compiled to IL but you get the point.

This means that you can only mark things as constant that are known at compile and are C# primitive objects, like string, int, decimal etc.

readonly is currently not allowed for variables unfortunately. However there is talk of making it possible https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/CSharp-Readonly-Locals

Answer (score 1):

1. You can not use `const`. You can think of `const` less like a variable, and more like a macro that replaces all instances with the value at compile time. It can only be used with strings and primitives.
2. You can only use `readonly` with fields, not with local variables. Maybe that should be allowed, but it is not.

Comment: I explain it by saying "Think of a `const` as a symbolic alias for a literal". If you can't use a literal, you can't use a const

Answer (score 0):

> When I do that, I get an error, "The expression being assigned to cert must be a constant".

Ignoring what you want, and looking at the limitations of what c# provides for *const* values:  [const (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const).

> Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null reference.

I don't know what else to tell you, you simply can't use an instantiated object.

Now an alternate way to create a somewhat safe *readonly* object is to only expose an interface:

```
public class MyFactory
{
    public IKeyGen GenerateKeyProvider()
    {
        return new KeyGen();
    }

    public interface IKeyGen 
    {
      int GetKey(string arg);
    }

    private class KeyGen : IKeyGen
    {
        public int GetKey(string arg)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Since you've not included any *usage* of this object, it's extremely hard to determine anything other than you don't want the object itself to change.